# Should I thank thesis committee before defense?

Tags: defense, thesis-committee

I want to email a copy of my thesis to the thesis committee, should I thank them that they are serving on my thesis/dissertation committee? and how should I thank them?
(it is before my defense))

Comment: I downvoted because it is an extremely trivial question.

Comment: @Ketan That criticism could be levelled at a great number of questions on here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should thank them by acknowledging them at the end of your defense (i.e. the acknowledgment slide of your PowerPoint presentation). Keep it professional though. Once your defense is over and you are cleared for graduation, then you can shake their hands and get a beer.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think including a sentence ,e.g., "thank you for serving on my dissertation committee" would be unprofessional?

Comment: You can just put "thesis commitee" and underneath that list the names of the members. As you narrate the slide you can say "I would also like to thank the members of my thesis committee.....etc."